# Javascript - how to tell the video element to stop playing the video at xyz duration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, video

I have content in French, Nederland, English (on same topic example: "global warming" )

But its in one large file, how can i tell the video element to please play from duration 00:00:00 till 00:05:00 only do not play the whole 02:00:00 ?

```
function video_play_onetime_withcut(input) {
  $('#mediaplayer').prop('loop', false);     
  $('#mediaplayer').attr('src', filename).show();
  mediaplay_video= document.getElementById('mediaplayer');
  mediaplay_video.play();  
  mediaplay_video.onended = function(e) {
    console.log('>>> Playing finished: ', e);
  };
}
```

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: @blink-fish Since the post is tagged with HTML5, I'd say it's simply HTML5 video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `timeupdate` event.

```
mediaplay_video.ontimeupdate = function(event) {
  if( mediaplay_video.currentTime === 5 * 60 ) {
    mediaplay_video.pause();

    // Just so we don't stop the player multiple times if the user
    //   wants to see the whole thing...
    mediaplay_video.ontimeupdate = false;

    // Do whatever you want.
  }
};
```

If you plan to hide the player afterwards, you can use this:

```
mediaplay_video.ontimeupdate = function(event) {
  if( mediaplay_video.currentTime >= 5 * 60 ) {
    mediaplay_video.pause();
    // @TODO: Remove player element...
  }
};
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp).

Comment: This is the correct way to go. Using larger-equal instead of equal sounds like a good idea though.

Comment: Could be, but that's only if the video is intended to be hidden. If not, it will cause the player to stop every second. I've added both cases to my answer.

Comment: @Louy: thanks. is it possible to find any videos total duration while play started?  i want to use your method but end the video always before 6 seconds to the end (because i have very random clips and they all before 6 second has some RGB color's)

Comment: @YumYumYum No problem. Check the link I added in the end, there's a property called `duration` that you can use.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to use a timeout function.

```
var clipLength = 10000; //milliseconds
window.setTimeout(function(){
    mediaplay_video.stop();
}, clipLength);
```

Comment: This is a bad way to handle it as the video might take some time to load. Think about slow internet connections.

Comment: Timeouts are _never_ accurate, don't do this.